# Error 403, Response to preflight request. after PUT AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, rest, put

I am having trouble in using this function :

```
$scope.modificaPassword = function () {
    var loginId,token,newPass,oldPass;

    loginId = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage['user']).loginId;
    token = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage['user']).token;
    oldPass = $scope.cambioPasswordData.oldpassword;
    newPass = $scope.cambioPasswordData.newpassword1;

    $http({
       method: "PUT",
       url: "http:// . . . /cqrest/api/webapp/auth/login",
       headers: {
         'loginId': loginId,
         'token': token,
         'oldpassword': oldPass,
         'newpassword': newPass
       },
     }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
       if(response.data){
         alert("Password modificata correttamente");
       }else{
         if($scope.checkToken()){
           alert("La vecchia password non corrisponde");
         }else{
           //disconnesso
         }
       }
     }, function myError(response) {
       alert("Errore " + response.data);

       $scope.error = response.data;

     });
  }
```

I need to contact a rest service to change an account password, the problem is that

```
Failed to load http://. . . /api/webapp/auth/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:// . . . ' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
2angular.min.js:93 
OPTIONS http:// . . . /cqrest/api/webapp/auth/login 403 ()
    (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:93
    q @ angular.min.js:89
    g @ angular.min.js:86
    (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:118
    $eval @ angular.min.js:132
    $digest @ angular.min.js:129
    $apply @ angular.min.js:133
    (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:252
    dispatch @ jqueryb8ff.js?ver=1.12.4:3
    r.handle @ jqueryb8ff.js?ver=1.12.4:3
```

I have already use angular to call rest put callbacks, but i have never got this error yet. What should I do ?
I have also tried to use postman to check if the service was working properly, and it is... and the paramethers are passed in the correct way.

Comment: the api you try accessing are made by you ??? ... if it is, check the allow methods options to accept the preflight headers.

Comment: what should I do to avoid this issue, the api are sited on a server that i can not access.